# Enjoy an eminence?

Tags: word-usage, collocation

I'm wondering if I can use the word "eminence" in order to say that a country is much admired or has a very good reputation.
And then - I couldn't find collocations for eminence - can I say "The country enjoys an eminence"?

Comment: If by enjoy you mean *have* or *possess* (but not *like*) then yes that's okay. See the definitions in [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enjoy). You can use definition 2 with *an eminence*.

Comment: But you probably want to 'qualify' *an eminence* somehow, such as by using a relative clause (*The country enjoys an eminence that it hasn't had in years*) because we don't usually use mass/noncount  nouns with the indefinite article. So *The country enjoys an eminence* sounds a little strange without qualifying it by describing **what type** of eminence it has.

Comment: Thanks a lot that sounds reasonable. I didn't expect I'd get an answer this fast. cool. I'm gonna use this more often from now on. So that means I can say that it enjoys a high eminence? Or good eminence? or extraordinary? Sth like that?

Comment: That kind of usage is not ungrammatical. How good it sounds may depend on the context and formality of the text.

Comment: You would probably say that something enjoys high eminence.

Comment: "High eminence" is problematic since the opposite would be "low eminence"... and is that possible? Rather, why not refer to how broadly recognized that eminence is by using the phrase "broadly recognized eminence" or "well regarded eminence" or simply "eminence" in the particular field you want to praise without a qualifier. You can hold something in high esteem or low esteem, but I don't think it is proper to hold something in high eminence since low eminence is nonsensical.

Comment: @Steve what's nonsensical is insisting that every quality have an opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the word "appreciate". This can mean both that a country actively enjoys the eminence that is bestowed upon it and that it respects it in a purely legalistic fashion, permitting you to humanise the entity a little.

> Historically, the country has appreciated an air of eminence from its neighbours to the east.

You may also state directly that the country is "treated" with eminence from others near to it:

> Despite its domestic political woes, the area continues to be treated with eminence by those who once would have called it a mother country.